# $('body').css('overflow-y', 'auto') doesn't work on Internet explorer

Tags: jquery, css

I'm trying to have diferent browser behaviours depending on window height.
What I want is
if user is on a netbook my script will just activate the css overflow-y to 'auto' so if content is bigger than screen user can see everything.
if user is in a big screen, I want to have overflow hidden and just have my main div with overflow = 'auto', so the footer can be at bottom of screen, but content can also be viwed if bigger than screen.

posting the basic code for this, it works on big screens on mac, but on internet explorer it doesn't, either on big or small screens...

what to do?

Thanks for help in advance

CSS

```
html, body {
    min-width: 600px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#header {
    position:relative;  /* IE7 overflow bug */
    clear:both;
    float:left;
    width:100%;
    height: 200px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#main {
    position:relative;  /* IE7 overflow bug */
    clear:both;
    float:left;
    width:100%;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
#footer {
    position:relative;  /* IE7 overflow bug */
    clear:both;
    float:left;
    width:100%;
    height: 100px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

jQuery

```
if( typeof( window.innerWidth ) == 'number' ) {
    // No-IE
    var screen_height = window.innerHeight;
} else if( document.documentElement && ( document.documentElement.clientWidth || document.documentElement.clientHeight ) ) {
    //IE 6 +
    var screen_height = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
} else if( document.body && ( document.body.clientWidth || document.body.clientHeight ) ) {
    //IE 4
    var screen_height = document.body.clientHeight;
}

var header_height = $('#header').height();
var footer_height = $('#footer').height();
var main_height = screen_height - header_height - footer_height;
//
if (navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().search("iphone") > -1 || navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().search("ipod") > -1) {
    $('body').css('overflow-y', 'auto');
} else {
    if(screen_height > 550) {
        $('#main').css('height', main_height + 'px');
$('#main').css('overflow-y', 'auto');
    } else {
        $('html, body').css('overflow-y', 'auto');
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly happens or doesn't happen on IE
?

Comment: Hello, in IE overflow is always hidden, so I can't see all the content. Testing in IE 7, 8 and 9. Thanks.

Comment: Does anything happen if you get rid of the !important?

Comment: Dont have any computer now to test, sorry. Thanks

Comment: Removing the important! didn't solve the bug, this is only working good in mac on every browser I've.

Comment: According to a [document](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc351024(v=vs.85).aspx) by Microsoft, overflow-y should be supported on all the IE versions you listed.  Does overflow-y work when included in the stylesheet?

Comment: ok, after many testes, dicover that for ie, we must use html, not body overflow. now its working on macs and on all browsers I've, IE 7, 8, 9, Firefox and Chrome In windows. Thanks

Answer (score 46, accepted):

```
$('html, body').css('overflowY', 'auto');
```

solves this problem.

Comment: What happened to the dash: was it intentionally omitted, or is that a typo?

Answer (score 8):

Try setting it with `overflowY`:

```
$('body').css('overflowY', 'auto');
```

Dashes in attribute names typically don't work when set with JavaScript, especially in IE.

Hope that works.

Comment: just adding $('html') works like a charm, I've update the initial code for future searchers on this, but don't find where to say question solved :-(

Comment: Glad it worked! There should be a link to accept the answer as correct right underneath it.